# Stop other videos after lazyload new one - jQuery and youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-api

My Scenario - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/evavienna/pen/ggNXrM) (Don't forget to scroll down)

Im using the [lazyframe plugin](https://github.com/viktorbergehall/lazyframe) to lazyload my youtube iframe videos. Each video gets added to the DOM after a click on the play button. There is a onAppend function included wich gets triggerd after a new video iframe is created (please have a look at the pen i created).

**How can i stop the other vids after starting a new one?**

I put a alert into the onAppend function to check if it works fine. The onAppend part looks like

```
    onAppend: function(e) {
        alert('onAppend after Lazyframe Function');                    
    }
```

I also managed to include the following scripts

```
    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

The part at the end of the embed youtube url to enable the API is also inclulde

```
    &enablejsapi=1
```

Each Iframe gets a unique id

```
    <iframe id="lazyframe-6hgVihWjK2c" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6hgVihWjK2c/?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen="" class="test-vidx" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I take from what you have said, that you are loading your page with many players at the same time. If so, you are finding out that they are independent from each other.

If this is so, you are then wanting to have only one play at any one time.

Only thing I can think of is to set up a dynamic variable that you load the ID of the currently selected player into. Then when you select to play a different video, you send a stop command to the old video using the variable for ID. Then update the variable with the new video players ID . However I am not sure how you will grab the ID as the imbedded players from the api call don't seem to have one.

Best is to use a stand alone player which you can give ID's to.
Here is the relevant [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like the old lazyYT, I just added these two lines inside the click event of the lazyYT js code and it seems to be working pretty well :)

```
        $(<loaded-video-class-name>).lazyYT();
        $(<loaded-video-class-name>).removeClass(<loaded-video-class-name>);
```

Basically, onclick it'll reload the video thumbnail inside any element that was previously loaded with a video, and reset the element by removing the added class upon initial click to return to its initial state.